# Jekyll Post - selecting several different posts from different categories

Tags: post, jekyll, blogs, portfolio, jekyll-theme

Currently, I am building out a Jekyll website as a portfolio and a blog for my self. I want to make custom pages for job posting with the selected post being used. Example maybe only 3 portfolio project that is relevant to the employer and 3 blog posts that are relative to the employer. I would want to mix and match these for each job I apply for to give them all a custom experience.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways to do this.

#### 1. Make a layout for your portfolio, and then create pages using that layout for each portfolio/employer.

- create a portfolio layout called `portfolio.html` and put it in your `_layouts` directory
- create a markdown file for each custom portfolio with this YAML

```
---
layout: portfolio
title: "Custom Title"
permalink: /custom-permalink/
---
```

#### 2. Create a seperate .html file in the root directory for each portfolio/employer

Normally you would have an index.html file with the blog posts in your root directory. Simply make other files like `company-1.html`, `company-2.html`, `portfolio-1.html` etc., but fill those index files with the posts or projects that you want to show.

**Note**: to get clean links like `https://yoursite.com/portfolio-1/` you may need to set this in your `_config.yaml`

```
permalink:        "/:title/"
```

For more details on how to do all this see the [Jekyll Docs for Creating Pages](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) as well as the information about [how to link to posts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#linking-to-posts) and [how to link to pages](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#linking-to-posts).